# Chat Bot is not working - HTTPS internal server error

Tags: botframework, web-chat

I have created a sample Echo bot for testing i've followed the given instructions in the MS tutorial site.

Created a web app service
Downloaded the MS bot framework v4 SDK - Echo Bot
Got the Publishing profile
Published the bot using visual studio
tested the chat bot When i test my bot in Test in Web Chat option in bot channels registration.

before that i tested in bot framework emulator, it was working fine as expected.

I checked the microsoft appid and password, it is all fine.

what am i missing to look on. can anyone please guide me.

[image]

Comment: Have you tested the bot on any other channel? Can you try making use of [ngrok](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/10/19/debug-channel-locally-using-ngrok/) and try debugging the bot locally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found the issue, though it a minor mistake. I wanted to update it here since many new Azure Bot users might do this mistake like me.

It was due to the option which i selected in while doing the app registration, After selecting the third option  for **Who can use this application or access this API?**

It always good to select Multitenant option to make the bot to work for everyone.

If your requirement is restricted to one particular tenant then you should select the first option. But it is not in my case.

> Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory -
> Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)

[image]